# Printing priority_queue comprising pair

Tags: vector, iterator, priority-queue, std-pair

Hello My program is..

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof(c.begin()) i =c.begin();i!=c.end();i++)
#define all(c) c.begin(),c.end()

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,V;cin>>V;
    vector< pair<char,int> > spt(V);
    vector< pair<char,int> >::iterator iv;

    for(i=0;i<V;i++)
    {
        spt[i].first = 65+i;
        spt[i].second = i+1;
    }

    tr(spt,iv)
    cout<<iv->first<<" - "<<iv->second<<endl;

    priority_queue< pair< char,int > , vector< pair<char,int> > , greater< pair <char,int> > > p(all(spt));



}
```

Now 
    how will i retrieve the values from priority_queue 'p' as
    i) priority_queue doesn't have its own iterator
    ii)it doesnot accepts vector's iterator as well
    iii) p.top is not class value type

Thanks in advance